# Agrupar os dados por uma determinada coluna no R

Tags: r

Eu peguei alguns dados, pois são 1704 obs. de  6 variáveis. Então selecionei as 80 primeiras linhas. Segue o código abaixo:

`structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", 
"Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Belgium", "Benin", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", 
"Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", 
"Congo, Rep.", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", 
"Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", 
"Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", 
"Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Germany", 
"Ghana", "Greece", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Haiti", 
"Honduras", "Hong Kong, China", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", 
"Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", 
"Japan", "Jordan", "Kenya", "Korea, Dem. Rep.", "Korea, Rep.", 
"Kuwait", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Madagascar", 
"Malawi", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", 
"Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", 
"Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", 
"Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Paraguay", 
"Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Reunion", 
"Romania", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Senegal", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovak Republic", 
"Slovenia", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", 
"Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", 
"Turkey", "Uganda", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", 
"Venezuela", "Vietnam", "West Bank and Gaza", "Yemen, Rep.", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), continent = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Africa", 
"Americas", "Asia", "Europe", "Oceania"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
    1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 
    1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 
    1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 
    2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
    1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 
    1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 
    1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 1987L, 1992L, 1997L, 
    2002L, 2007L, 1952L, 1957L, 1962L, 1967L, 1972L, 1977L, 1982L, 
    1987L), lifeExp = c(28.801, 30.332, 31.997, 34.02, 36.088, 
    38.438, 39.854, 40.822, 41.674, 41.763, 42.129, 43.828, 55.23, 
    59.28, 64.82, 66.22, 67.69, 68.93, 70.42, 72, 71.581, 72.95, 
    75.651, 76.423, 43.077, 45.685, 48.303, 51.407, 54.518, 58.014, 
    61.368, 65.799, 67.744, 69.152, 70.994, 72.301, 30.015, 31.999, 
    34, 35.985, 37.928, 39.483, 39.942, 39.906, 40.647, 40.963, 
    41.003, 42.731, 62.485, 64.399, 65.142, 65.634, 67.065, 68.481, 
    69.942, 70.774, 71.868, 73.275, 74.34, 75.32, 69.12, 70.33, 
    70.93, 71.1, 71.93, 73.49, 74.74, 76.32, 77.56, 78.83, 80.37, 
    81.235, 66.8, 67.48, 69.54, 70.14, 70.63, 72.17, 73.18, 74.94
    ), pop = c(8425333L, 9240934L, 10267083L, 11537966L, 13079460L, 
    14880372L, 12881816L, 13867957L, 16317921L, 22227415L, 25268405L, 
    31889923L, 1282697L, 1476505L, 1728137L, 1984060L, 2263554L, 
    2509048L, 2780097L, 3075321L, 3326498L, 3428038L, 3508512L, 
    3600523L, 9279525L, 10270856L, 11000948L, 12760499L, 14760787L, 
    17152804L, 20033753L, 23254956L, 26298373L, 29072015L, 31287142L, 
    33333216L, 4232095L, 4561361L, 4826015L, 5247469L, 5894858L, 
    6162675L, 7016384L, 7874230L, 8735988L, 9875024L, 10866106L, 
    12420476L, 17876956L, 19610538L, 21283783L, 22934225L, 24779799L, 
    26983828L, 29341374L, 31620918L, 33958947L, 36203463L, 38331121L, 
    40301927L, 8691212L, 9712569L, 10794968L, 11872264L, 13177000L, 
    14074100L, 15184200L, 16257249L, 17481977L, 18565243L, 19546792L, 
    20434176L, 6927772L, 6965860L, 7129864L, 7376998L, 7544201L, 
    7568430L, 7574613L, 7578903L), gdpPercap = c(779.4453145, 
    820.8530296, 853.10071, 836.1971382, 739.9811058, 786.11336, 
    978.0114388, 852.3959448, 649.3413952, 635.341351, 726.7340548, 
    974.5803384, 1601.056136, 1942.284244, 2312.888958, 2760.196931, 
    3313.422188, 3533.00391, 3630.880722, 3738.932735, 2497.437901, 
    3193.054604, 4604.211737, 5937.029526, 2449.008185, 3013.976023, 
    2550.81688, 3246.991771, 4182.663766, 4910.416756, 5745.160213, 
    5681.358539, 5023.216647, 4797.295051, 5288.040382, 6223.367465, 
    3520.610273, 3827.940465, 4269.276742, 5522.776375, 5473.288005, 
    3008.647355, 2756.953672, 2430.208311, 2627.845685, 2277.140884, 
    2773.287312, 4797.231267, 5911.315053, 6856.856212, 7133.166023, 
    8052.953021, 9443.038526, 10079.02674, 8997.897412, 9139.671389, 
    9308.41871, 10967.28195, 8797.640716, 12779.37964, 10039.59564, 
    10949.64959, 12217.22686, 14526.12465, 16788.62948, 18334.19751, 
    19477.00928, 21888.88903, 23424.76683, 26997.93657, 30687.75473, 
    34435.36744, 6137.076492, 8842.59803, 10750.72111, 12834.6024, 
    16661.6256, 19749.4223, 21597.08362, 23687.82607)), row.names = c(NA, 
80L), class = "data.frame")`

Quero quantidade de países por continente no R. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Usando `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  distinct(country) %>% 
  count()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   continent [5]
continent     n
<fct>     <int>
1 Africa        2
2 Americas      1
3 Asia          1
4 Europe        2
5 Oceania       1
```

**Edição (solicitada no campo de comentários)**

Por padrão, uma `tibble` retorna apenas as primeiras observações ao Console. Se precisar ver todas as observações, insira a função `as.data.frame` ao final do código, já que um `data.frame` não controla o número de linhas retornadas. Ficaria assim:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  distinct(country) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

No entanto, isto é pouco útil pelo seguinte motivo: desorganização da análise. Suponha que você tenha um banco de dados com 10.000 casos. Retronar tudo ao Console não é uma ação sábia, pois vai se perder daquilo que já fez antes.

Se está a usar o `RStudio`, você pode criar um objeto e empregar a função `View` para ver todas as observações:

```
meu <- data %>% 
         group_by(continent) %>% 
         distinct(country) %>% 
         count()

View(meu)
```

Comment: Se tiver a mensagem with 132 more rows, tem como listar todos os resultados? Quando um conjunto de dados são muito grandes, ele mostra só alguns.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se atende ao que deseja.

Comment: Ah Entendi. Não lembrava do view. Muito melhor agora. Muito obrigado. valeu

Answer (score 2):

Em R base pode usar o `aggregate`.
Note que chamei aos dados `dados`.

```
aggregate(country ~ continent, dados, function(x) length(unique(x)))
#  continent country
#1    Africa       2
#2  Americas       1
#3      Asia       1
#4    Europe       2
#5   Oceania       1
```

Para ordenar este resultado por ordem decrescente de número de países, deve-se guardar o resultado e depois aplicar `order`.

```
continentes <- aggregate(country ~ continent, dados, function(x) length(unique(x)))
continentes <- continentes[order(continentes$country, decreasing = TRUE), ]

continentes
#  continent country
#1    Africa       2
#4    Europe       2
#2  Americas       1
#3      Asia       1
#5   Oceania       1
```

Comment: Tenho como ordenar do maior para o menor. Ou seja, Nesse aí, a África e a Europa tem 2 cada. Queria que aparece primeiro. Tem como?

Comment: @FidelHenriqueFernandes Feito, veja a edição da resposta.